# How to build an image using json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, image

I need a way to build the image using json data provided. I have json file, which contains user portfolio. At the end of the day I want to convert the json data to an image, so that I need to make a graph for every time user enters the page. But I am clue less about how to start.

the json file looks like

```
 {
   {
      "time": 1585440000,
      "closing_balance": 5882.2
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 6403.31
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 7403.31
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 5403.31
   },...
}
```

Now I want to show the above data in graph format by converting to image once in a day.

Comment: maybe add more details? how does the json file look like? I'm confused wether there is an image inside the json file you want to extract or there is just normal data which you want to build a graph of? maybe share also what the result expectation could look like?

Comment: I will add the details

Answer (score 1):

your json data is pretty straight forward so you could in a controller read the JSON file and use it with a gem like https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

you will need to make your data usable by the gem first, you just need to read the json file and map the dates to the values (assuming you want a line or bar charts)

#### in your controller:

```rb
json_file = File.read('path-to-your-file.json')
data = JSON.parse(json_file)
@data = data.each_with_object({}) do |data_hash, new_hash|
  new_hash[Time.at(data_hash["time"]).to_datetime] = data_hash["closing_balance"]
end
# this will give you something like: {Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 +0000=>5882.2, Mon, 30 Mar 2020 01:00:00 +0100=>5403.31}
```

#### In your view:

```
  <%= line_chart @data %>
```

make sure to install gem probably (documentation in gem link above)

and note that your current json file (the one you sent) is broken it should be an array holding multiple hashes and not a hash holding multiple hashes without keys

```json
[
   {
      "time": 1585440000,
      "closing_balance": 5882.2
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 6403.31
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 7403.31
   },
   {
      "time": 1585526400,
      "closing_balance": 5403.31
   }
]
```

and that multiple times are the same so chart will only display first value at that time